# Testing Table component Ant-Design

Tags: reactjs, html-table, jestjs, antd, responsive

I'm trying to test the ant-design Table component, but I'm facing a mystery. Currently, my test is working; I can find the first name 'Mike' in the document. However, as soon as I uncomment the responsive field: ['lg'] in the columns, the test fails, and the first name 'Mike' doesn't appear.

Here is my code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Table } from 'antd';

it('render correctly name', () => {
  const dataSource = [
    {
      key: '1',
      name: 'Mike',
      age: 32,
      address: '10 Downing Street',
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      name: 'John',
      age: 42,
      address: '10 Downing Street',
    },
  ];

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
    //   responsive: ['lg'], //HERE
    },
    {
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
      key: 'age',
    },
    {
      title: 'Address',
      dataIndex: 'address',
      key: 'address',
    },
  ];
  const { getByText } = render(
    <Table data={dataSource} columns={columns} />,
  );

  expect(getByText('Mike')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I tried changing the responsive to xs, md...
I also attempted to set a window.width before my tests, but nothing seems to work. As soon as I remove that line, the test works. I find it crazy!

Thanks so much !